# javascript canvas detect click on shape

Tags: javascript, function, events, canvas, click

I have a problem with the click function in javascript. This is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

BigCircle = function(x, y, color, circleSize) {
    ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
    ctx.shadowColor = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, circleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
};

var bigGreen = new BigCircle(1580, 800, '#5eb62b', 180);

function init() {
    $("#bigGreen").click(function(e){
    alert("test");              
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});
```

But the click event is not working! Does anybody know why? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You need to post your HTML - I can't see what "canvas" or "bigGreen" are, and that is likely where the problem lies, in a mismatch of HTML and JavaScript names.

Comment: oh sorry, well here is the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/Babsi/eadBu/1/

Comment: This post may help: https://medium.com/devtravel/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8#.wgzhx52ns

Answer (score 17, accepted):

without seeing your html this question is a little bit unclear, it seems you would like to draw something on a canvas and use jquery to add click events for the circle, this isn't possible.

you can use jquery to get the click event ON the canvas and from the cursor position you can calculate if the user clicked the circle or not, but jquery won't help you here you have to do the math yourself.

jquery does only work for dom elements.

```
BigCircle = function(ctx,x, y, color, circleSize) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, circleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fillStyle=color
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    this.clicked=function(){
      ctx.fillStyle='#ff0000'
      ctx.fill();
    }
};

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var bigGreen = new BigCircle(ctx,50, 50, '#5eb62b', 50);
  $('#canvas').click(function(e){
    var x = e.clientX
      , y = e.clientY          
    if(Math.pow(x-50,2)+Math.pow(y-50,2) < Math.pow(50,2))   
      bigGreen.clicked()
  })    
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    init();   
});
```

​

jsfiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/yXVrk/1/

Comment: Good, but would have been easier to read if `Math.pow(x-50,2)+Math.pow(y-50,2) < Math.pow(50,2)` would have been without magic numbers (circle.x, circle.y & circle.radius instead of '50').

Comment: @supernova, working fine with having only canvas on webpage, but after inserting content above canvas is not working. checkout in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yXVrk/310/

Answer (score 25):

<s>You can now use hit regions in Chrome and Firefox:</s>

<s>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Hit_regions_and_accessibility#Hit_regions</s>

(Edit: Hit regions are now obsolete)

or just use one of the many canvas APIs:

http://www.fabricjs.com/

http://www.createjs.com/easeljs

http://www.paperjs.org

etc...

Comment: but it is an experimental feature at now yet :(

Comment: Looking forward to when this is not an experimental feature.  Will make collision detection far easier.

Comment: No longer a solution. Officially Obsolete according to MDN web docs.

Comment: Guys,. I'm not normally a js dev.  Regarding paper, createjs, fabricjs, really is there one that is now the standard usual choice ?

Answer (score 10):

Canvas API function **isPointInPath**() can be used to assist with hit detection. This function can at least tell if mouse coordinates are within a complex shape without doing sophisticated math yourself. May work for simple shapes as well but my use case was for on a bezier curve path. However, you need to either incorporate this function in your drawing logic to test while paths are open or keep an array of Path2d objects to test against. I redraw on onClick handler and pass in mouse coords from event args, but I think I could have kept an array of Path2d objects instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath

Answer (score 0):

bigGreen is not in the HTML, so $("#bigGreen") selects nothing.  You can't put a click function on things like JavaScript functions; since they don't exist in the DOM, how could you click one?  You should replace #bigGreen with #canvas, since "canvas" is your HTML element.

I forked your fiddle to show this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JjRpN/).

**Edit**: If you want to see that the user clicked on a particular circle, you use the canvas click event, and then, you determine which circle was clicked by the coordinates passed into the click event.

Comment: so I need to add more canvas? But I need about 40 Circles, so I must add 40 canvas? Is there a better solution?

Comment: No, one canvas.  I edited my answer.  You need to check the click mouse coordinates.

Comment: BTW, if your circles don't overlap the simplest way is to treat them as squares, that contain the circle, which are very easy to track by x,y coordinate as x,y,width,height rectangles.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately they do overlap :(

Comment: Since you've now accepted someone else's answer, I'll just give you the hint that you will then have to keep a z-order for your circles to resolve coordinate conflicts.