# Best way to handle mouseclicks upon sprites in Javascript HTML5 + Canvas

Tags: javascript, event-handling, click, mouseevent, mousedown

I have mostly used ActionScript 3 for my previous projects. Therefore I have gotten used to applying MouseEvent.CLICK directly to Sprites in order to registrer mouseclicks upon them.

What is the easiest way of doing this in JavaScript? Do I have to create my own function comparing the coordinates of the mouseclick with the coordinates of the object?

Comment: I suppose you're using the `canvas` element... then yes you have to compare the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question right, I think you need to define element.addEventListener("click",function) method. (element = sprite)

You will find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

And if you need support for IE older than IE9, look also for attachEvent()

EDIT: Now I saw your edited question....
Have you seen this: [javascript canvas detect click on shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625766/javascript-canvas-detect-click-on-shape)